# When zipping two Datasets, some samples are never chosen

Tags: python, tensorflow

How come some samples are never picked when zipping two Datasets? Consider this toy example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# first dataset of length 3: [0..2]
d1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(3)
# second dataset of length 5: [100..104]
d2 = tf.data.Dataset.range(100, 105)

d = tf.data.Dataset.zip((d1, d2)).repeat()
batch = d.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
for _ in range(10):
  print(sess.run(batch))
```

This outputs

```
(0, 100)
(1, 101)
(2, 102)
(0, 100)
(1, 101)
(2, 102)
(0, 100)
(1, 101)
(2, 102)
(0, 100)
```

The last 10 samples of `d2` are never picked.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when two zipped `Datasets` do not have the same length. The problem is that when `repeat` will catch the `OutOfRangeError` emitted by `d1`, it will reset `d1` *and* `d2`. So `d2` will start over even though it has not reached the end.

You could think of suppressing the `OutOfRangeError` from the shortest data set by making it loop,

```
import tensorflow as tf

d1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(3).repeat()
d2 = tf.data.Dataset.range(100, 105)

d = tf.data.Dataset.zip((d1, d2)).repeat()
batch = d.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
for _ in range(10):
  print(sess.run(batch))
```

but this brings a more subtle problem:

```
(0, 100)
(1, 101)
(2, 102)
(0, 103)
(1, 104)
(0, 100)
(1, 101)
(2, 102)
(0, 103)
(1, 104)
```

Now all samples are drawn, but not equally: `d2` now emits an `OutOfRangeError` when it reaches the end, and that reinitializes `d1`. So the first samples of `d1` are more likely to be chosen that the last ones. (This is still true if `d1` is shuffled, because shuffling happens in a buffer that is not of infinite length.)

The solution is to `repeat` both data sets *before* zipping them:

```
import tensorflow as tf

d1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(3).repeat()
d2 = tf.data.Dataset.range(100, 105).repeat()

d = tf.data.Dataset.zip((d1, d2))
batch = d.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
for _ in range(10):
  print(sess.run(batch))
```

outputs

```
(0, 100)
(1, 101)
(2, 102)
(0, 103)
(1, 104)
(2, 100)
(0, 101)
(1, 102)
(2, 103)
(0, 104)
```

This allows you to limit training in terms of epochs of one of the data sets, depending on what makes sense for a given problem, using the `count` argument of `repeat` for that data set.